# Creating an SQLite database with robolectric test ends in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, robolectric

I am trying to execute a simple create-a-database smoke test via robolectric as follows:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DBTest {

    @Test
    public void testSmoke() {
        ShadowActivity activity = new ShadowActivity();
        File f = activity.getDatabasePath("mydb");
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(f, null);
    }
}
```

But what I get is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy  (SQLiteConnection.java:1036)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dalvik.system.BlockGuard$Policy
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.findClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:119)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(AsmInstrumentingClassLoader.java:95)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.$$robo$$SQLiteConnection_19f8_applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1036)
  ...
```

A simple reference test of `assertEquals(true, true)` works fine. The `getDatabasePath()` method returns a valid path to a file in `/tmp/`. Could have been a "broken installation" but that was also ruled out. I've been stuck with this for hours and got out of ideas. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: would be also very interested in any solution :)